# How do I fix setManagedObjectContext error?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Whenever I run my app it always crashes and gives me this error:

> 2014-08-10 12:50:58.802 EIC Scanner[2184:133860] -[UITabBarController
>   setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7ae7b9f0 (lldb)

I have an exception breakpoint so it leads me to this line of code:

```
rootView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

Part of AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "NotesList.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // IMPORTANT: Pass the managedObjectContext to the root view controller
    NotesList *rootView = (NotesList *)_window.rootViewController;
    rootView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

return YES;
}
```

As requested NotesList.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface NotesList : UIViewController <
UITableViewDelegate,
UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate
>

// CoreData properties  *******
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *notesArray;

//UI VIEWS ***********
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *topView;

//TableView ********
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

If you know how to fix this, please comment on how. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please, provide more info. From your question it's unclear what you are doing and what is going wrong

Comment: Did you receive any warnings from the compiler when you built the project?

Comment: @tsnorri No I did not, it just crashes.

Comment: @AlexeyShmalko Added more info.

Comment: Sure looks like _window.rootViewController is returning an object that doesn't have a managedObjectContext selector.  Despite your cast as NotesList*, the type may not be that.  You should try checking it with isKindOfClass.  And if it's not what you expect, you can usually manage the class in Interface Builder by setting the class of various views.

Comment: Can you show NotesList.h, too?

Comment: @stevesliva My storyboard is a tabbed application and I have two tabs, what would be the _window.rootViewController?

Comment: @tsnorri Added NotesList.h.

Comment: @stevesliva I do slightly understand what you are saying now that I re-read your comment. Do you think you could break it down a little bit more?

Comment: [This Apple article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-storyboard/StoryboardScene.html) breaks down how to check the class of the VC -- you just need to check that it's NotesList.  It may or may not be something you expect to be done automatically... I'm unsure on iOS at the moment.

Comment: @stevesliva I checked it and it is NotesList.